# Memory issue with ItemsControl and DataBinding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I'm developing a debug view for my WPF application, which prints a large amount of data (several thousands of items) inside an ItemsControl.

Each item is pretty simple, as shown below:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Frames,
                                          Mode=OneTime}"
                    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
          <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <Grid Margin="50,0,0,0">
                      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                          <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                          <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                          <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                          <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                          <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                          <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDefinition />
                          <ColumnDefinition />
                      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  Orientation="Horizontal">
                          <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="Date (HH:mm::ss::FFF)" />
                          <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                     FontSize="16"
                                     Text="|" />
                          <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="Frame number" />
                      </StackPanel>
                      <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  Orientation="Horizontal">
                          <TextBlock FontSize="16"
                                     Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundSelected}"
                                     Text="{Binding date,
                                                    Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToFullDateConverter}}" />
                          <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                     FontSize="16"
                                     Text="|" />
                          <TextBlock FontSize="16"
                                     Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundSelected}"
                                     Text="{Binding frameNumber}" />
                      </StackPanel>

                      <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  Orientation="Horizontal">
                          <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="Framerate (in fps)" />
                          <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                     FontSize="16"
                                     Text="|" />
                          <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="Bitrate (in kB/s)" />
                      </StackPanel>
                      <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  Orientation="Horizontal">
                          <TextBlock FontSize="16"
                                     Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundSelected}"
                                     Text="{Binding framerate}" />
                          <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                     FontSize="16"
                                     Text="|" />
                          <TextBlock FontSize="16"
                                     Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundSelected}"
                                     Text="{Binding bitrate}" />
                      </StackPanel>
                      <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  Orientation="Horizontal">
                          <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="Width (in pixels)" />
                          <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                     FontSize="16"
                                     Text="|" />
                          <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="Height (in pixels)" />
                      </StackPanel>

                      <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  Orientation="Horizontal">
                          <TextBlock FontSize="16"
                                     Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundSelected}"
                                     Text="{Binding width}" />
                          <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                     FontSize="16"
                                     Text="|" />
                          <TextBlock FontSize="16"
                                     Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundSelected}"
                                     Text="{Binding height}" />
                      </StackPanel>
                      <TextBlock Grid.Row="3"
                                 Grid.Column="0"
                                 FontSize="16"
                                 Text="Delay (in milliseconds)" />
                      <TextBlock Grid.Row="3"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 FontSize="16"
                                 Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundSelected}"
                                 Text="{Binding delay}" />

                      <TextBlock Grid.Row="4"
                                 Grid.Column="0"
                                 FontSize="16"
                                 Text="Type" />
                      <TextBlock Grid.Row="4"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 FontSize="16"
                                 Foreground="{StaticResource BackgroundSelected}"
                                 Text="{Binding type}" />
                      <Separator Grid.Row="5"
                                 Grid.Column="0"
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                 Margin="5" />
                  </Grid>
              </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
   </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

My Frames property is bound to an ObservableCollection and I call Add method 60 times per second.

The problem is, my memory consumption jumps as soon as the collection contains hundred of items (start from 250MB and raise to 700MB+ in 30 seconds), and my CPU usage is really high too...

I'm aware of the performance issues that WPF suffers but I'm wondering if it's possible to show thousands items in my control without crashing my app.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does it ever clear the ObservableCollection or does it just keep adding?

Comment: It just keep adding, I don't clear my collection